# ¿Cómo filtro las líneas de un csv que tienen un valor determinado?

Tags: python, string, csv, filtro

Estoy abriendo un archivo llamado: "plpcen.csv", y quiero filtrar ciertas filas que contengan el siguiente string: "Sim 1" y las filas filtradas guardarlas en otro archivo llamado: "plpcen_r.csv".

Estoy usando el siguiente codigo:

```
open('plpcen_r.csv','w').writelines([ line for line in open('plpcen.csv') if 'Sim 1' in line])
```

Sin embargo, me esta filtrando todas las filas que contienen:

- "Sim 1"
- "Sim 10"
- "Sim 11"
- "Sim 1x"

Solo quiero que filtre el "Sim 1".

*Mi problema es extraer las filas que contengan la "Sim1" pero no la "Sim 1x" porlo mismo es probable que se pueda agregar alguna condición adicional que deje afuera a todas las otras "Sim 1xx". ¿Que tipo de filtro o que tipo condición debería adicionar para lograr extraer solo el "Sim 1"?*

No puedo utilizar **Pandas** porque estoy ejecutando el script en un servidor externo que no tengo lo permisos para instalar dicha librería. Tengo que intentarlo hacer con las funciones basicas de python.

Acepto cualquier sugerencia.

Agrego imagen de la estructura del archivo que intento filtrar:

[image: El archivo que intento filtrar tiene la siguiente estructura]

Comment: en la línea de comandos puedes decir: `awk -F, '$2 == "Sim 1"' fichero.csv > filtrado.csv`

Comment: Efectivamente habia explorado la opción de awk en la linea de comando. Pero es probable realizar esto mismo pero en python?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dos soluciones

### 1. Tediosa de hacer

```
open('plpcen_r.csv','w').writelines([ line for line in open('plpcen.csv') if 'Sim 1' in line and not "Sim 11" in line and not "Sim 12" in line]) #etc...
```

Basicamente he ampliado tu ejemplo. exiges que se cumplan todas las condiciones anteriores a la vez.

### 2. Más divertida de hacer.

```
archivo = open('plpcen_r.csv', 'r')

lineas_filtradas = []
for line in archivo:
    filtro = line.split(',')
    if "Sim 1" == filtro[1]:
        lineas_filtradas.append(line)


archivo.close()

#Escribimos un nuevo archivo con las lineas filtradas
open('plpcen_r.csv','w').writelines([line for line in lineas_filtradas])
```

Suponiendo que tu archivo esté separado por comas (si no puedes cambiar al separador que estés usando) y que tu columna es la segunda, como aparece en la foto. Puedes coger esta idea.

- Primero abres el archivo en modo lectura con `open()`
- Lees linea por linea con el bucle `for`
- cada linea la separas con el método `split(',')` estableciendo el tipo de separador que use tu .csv (normalmente comas). Ahora  me creo una variable "filtro" que será una lista que representará una fila y dentro de esa lista estarán los valores que dicha fila tienen en cada columna.
- Ya solo te queda irte al indice 1 de esa lista, que representa tu segunda columna en el .csv y ver si es igual a "Sim1". En el caso de que sea igual lo añades a la variable "lineas_filtradas".
- Por último cierras el archivo con el método `.close()`

A partir de aquí ya puedes operar con las filas filtradas, guardarla, hacer lo que quieras!

Comment: Hola Alberto, te agradezco tu ayuda, sin embargo el archivo que intento abrir tienen otros campos además de la "Sim 1". Por lo que no tengo una linea solo con la palabra "Sim 1". Probé tu consejo y el archivo de salida queda vacio. Lamentablemente no puedo utlizar **Pandas** porque estoy ejecutando el escript en un servidor remoto que no tiene instalado dicha librería y tampoco tengo los permisos para instalarla.

Comment: pero entonces qué es lo que necesitas? qué contenga "Sim 1"? si es así, el código que tu pones hará que todos los que contengan "Sim 1" te lo devuelva. Si no es así, por favor edita la pregunta y explica mejor que es exactamente lo que necesitas, por favor. Aun así te he puesto la tercera opción por si es lo que necesitas.

Comment: Hola Alberto, te comento que intenté la tercerá opción que me indicas, pero el archivo que se genera esta vacio porque el campo que contiene a "Sim 1" en el archivo de origen no tiene espacio. Mi problema es extraer las filas que contengan la "Sim1" pero no la "Sim 1xx" porlo mismo es probable que se pueda agregar alguna condición adicional que deje afuera a todas las otras "Sim 1xx". Y esa es mu duda, ¿Que tipo de filtro o que tipo condición debería adicionar para lograr extraer solo el "Sim 1"?

Comment: Disculpame pero no logro entender tu problema. Por favor edita tu pregunta en el botón de editar, y agrega las columnas que tienes (o una muestra en el caso de que tengas muchas) y cual sería el resultado que deseas obtener. Perdoname pero no logro entenderte.

Comment: Lo acabo de hacer, gracias por tu sugerencia.

Comment: ya entiendo mejor tu problema. Te he editado la respuesta, pruébalo y me dices!

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!! Alberto,  funcionó la opción 2, tuve que hacer un pequeño ajuste: "Sim 1" == filtro[0]  era cambiar el indice y funcionó sin problemas. Saludos.

Comment: Me alegro de ser de ayuda!! Aunque como eres nuevo probablemente no lo sepas, la mejor forma de dar las gracias en StackOverflow en marcando la respuesta como "respuesta correcta" y por qué no, dar un voto positivo (cuando tengas reputación